# webpack 4 uglifyjs not minifying and compressing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, uglifyjs

I am using webpack 4 and I am unsure if my code is being compressed and minified. I am using React as well.

My first problem is using the Webpack UglifyJS plugin in the webpack `plugin` property or the `optimization` property. When I use the `plugin` property it seems to compress at least but not to a single line. I am still unsure if it is minifying. When I use `optimization` it does not even compress. When I take a look at my bundled js file, it seems to be bundling things in `node_modules` such as `webpack`.

//works with `plugin`

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        sourceMap: true,
        uglifyOptions: {
            compress: {},
            mangle: true,
        }
}],
```

//does not work with `optimization`

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new UglifyJsPlugin({
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            sourceMap: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: {},
                mangle: true,
             }
       }],
    }
```

With the first example, the code gets compressed at least but not into one single line.

//Example

```
!*** ./node_modules/scheduler/index.js ***!
  \*****************************************/
/*! no static exports found */function(module,exports,__webpack_require__){"use strict";eval('\n\nif (false) {} else {\n...

 !*** ./node_modules/scheduler/tracing.js ***!
  \*******************************************/
/*! no static exports found */function(module,exports,__webpack_require__){"use strict";eval('\n\nif (false) {...
```

Also not sure if it being minified. I wrote a function in my React Component

```
someFunc(one, two) {
    return one + two
}
```

According to the npm uglifyjs docs, this should be minified into

```
someFunc(a, b) { \n return a+b\n}
```

but it is being output as

```
someFunc(one, two) { \n return one + two\n}
```

Is this minifying?

Comment: Maybe you should switch to [`terser-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/terser-webpack-plugin). uglify-js doesn't support ES6+ features and uglify-es is no longer maintained. So if you will run into issues, you are on your own.

Comment: I am aiming to minify the transpiled JS code that runs through my webpack loaders. Basically I want to minify the bundle js file which should be es5

Answer (score 15):

Webpack 4 does optimization and minification by default in `production` mode.

So if my guess is right, your configuration is `development` configuration.

You can remove your explicit UglifyJsPlugin definition and set the `mode` to `production` and Webpack will take care of everything.

```
mode: 'production',
plugins: [...],
optimization: ...
```

You can customize your optimizations though if you must. But setting the mode to `production` will yield you your expected results.

More info here

[Webpack 4 mode usage](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/#usage)

Comment: Yes, I just found that out as well. Thanks you

Comment: @henhen If this answer helped you solve your problem, mark it as accepted answer. It will help others who stumble across similar problems.

Comment: Okay thanks. But my original questions were still not answered. Since the option to use webpack uglifyJS exists and can be used with the `optimization` property, I don't see or am unsure if it is minifying or why its not being compressed.

Comment: In my case to see any difference in build size I had to also add `uglifyJS` under webpack plugins entry: `plugins: [new UglifyJsPlugin()]`

This does not seem documented but only doing the `optimization` entry part did not reflect any changes in build size, I had to do both of them.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue. It started working after providing mode config value as production.

```
module.exports = {
    // webpack config
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
};

// command NODE_ENV=production webpack
```